# How to add custom attribute for image preview in angular file upload plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I get this plugin to do a upload of images: **[Angular File Plugin](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)**

I need that when I enter a new file, it create a form for each file containing some fields that I want to send with the file.
I could do this using the callback `onAfterAddingFile` that follows:

```
uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {
        var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
i.setAttribute('type',"text");
i.setAttribute('name',"title");

f.appendChild(i);
document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(f);
```

But now, I need to link each image with each form. I think that I need to create a custom attribute, like `data-frm` for example, to link them, isn't? How can I do that?